# Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version while deploying solution on my local andorid device

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin PCL project was working fine since I downloaded Android SDK Platform 27 and updated all NuGet packages.

When try to deploy solution to my device (running Android 7.1) I get this output error:

> *Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or
>   debugging it.*

Build log when debugging this project:

```
2>Starting deploy Xiaomi Redmi 4A ...
2>Deploying Xiaomi Redmi 4A ...
2>Build started.
2>Project "MobileApp.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.admir.instantcollect.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.admir.instantcollect-Signed.apk" 
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.admir.instantcollect-arm64-v8a.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.admir.instantcollect-arm64-v8a-Signed.apk" 
2>"zipalign.exe" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "MobileApp.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Build FAILED.
2>Build started.
2>Project "MobileApp.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.admir.instantcollect.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.admir.instantcollect-Signed.apk" 
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.2\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp.Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\com.admir.instantcollect-arm64-v8a.apk" "bin\Debug\\com.admir.instantcollect-arm64-v8a-Signed.apk" 
2>"zipalign.exe" exited with code 1.
2>Done building project "MobileApp.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
2>Build FAILED.
2>
2>Deploy failed on Xiaomi Redmi 4A
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried to build/clean-rebuild solution and it builds successfully.
Here is the build output log:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: MobileApp.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.1.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Runtime.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2052,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
1>  MobileApp.Android -> C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\MobileApp\MobileApp.Android\bin\Debug\mobileapp.android.dll
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" and "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "mscorlib, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Xml, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "2.0.5.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Core, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "3.5.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "3.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "6.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to Version "11.0.0.0" [C:\Users\DAFPC\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MobileApp\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Xml.Linq, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "3.5.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2245,3): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Serialization" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding><assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly><assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml.Linq" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" /><bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" /></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

- I have set the Target framework to *Android 8.1* latest platform.
- Target Android version: *Use compile using SDK version*.
- Minimum Android version: *Android 4.4*.

Here is a list of Android SDKs I have already installed:
[image]

I have tried to change the target platform to 7.1 but the situation gets even worse

I get the same error when using any AVD emulator.

Could anyone explain me why do i get this error, and what can I do to solve it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with all that you have recently made a change in your project which it is not supporting thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build and deploy the solution successfully, I used to disable Android package signing and leaving all fields blank under Android project properties.

> Project.Android>Properties>Android Package Signing> Uncheck *Sign the .APK...*

Answer (score 2):

When I encountered this in the past, the problem was that I was deploying to a device which already had a version of the app installed, and there were two possibilities:

1. The installed version had a version code greater than the version code I tried to deploy, and/or
2. The installed version was the Play Store version of my app, which cannot be overwritted by Xamarin.Android tools.

You may also see the error in the Error List:

```
ADB0030: Mono.AndroidTools.RequiresUninstallException: The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.
```

The solutions in my case were one or both of:

1. Uninstall the app from my device, either through the UI or using ADB from the command prompt (e.g. adb uninstall *packagename*), then try my deployment again.
2. Change the package manifest (Project.Android>Properties>Android Manifest) to have a higher version code than the one currently installed, then try my deployment again.